# Visual studio compiles but no .exe is created

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, compilation

I am trying to make a telemetry software for a college project. I am new to C++ as I am more used to Python. I followed a few tutorials and asked help from GPT3 to make it.

```
// Importation des librairies

#include "telemetry.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QTableView>



// Structure pour stocker les données de télémétrie

struct TelemetryData {
    double time;
    double distance;
    double speed;
    double acceleration;
    double acceleratorPressure;
    double brakePressure;
    double gpsPositionX;
    double gpsPositionY;
};


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------- Main ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{


    // ---------- Création des différents affichages, boutons et onglets --------



    QApplication app(argc, argv);


    // Créer la fenêtre principale de l'application

    QMainWindow window;
    window.setWindowTitle("Télémétrie");


    // Créer le layout principal de la fenêtre

    QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget(&window);
    QVBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(centralWidget);
    window.setCentralWidget(centralWidget);


    // Créer le widget QTabWidget et l'ajouter à l'interface utilisateur

    QTabWidget* tabWidget = new QTabWidget(centralWidget);
    mainLayout->addWidget(tabWidget);


    // Créer le premier onglet affichant le graphique de pression d'accélérateur et de frein

    QWidget* firstTab = new QWidget();
    QVBoxLayout* firstTabLayout = new QVBoxLayout(firstTab);


    // Créer le graphe de pression d'accélérateur et de frein

    QCustomPlot* pressureGraph = new QCustomPlot(firstTab);
    pressureGraph->addGraph();
    pressureGraph->addGraph();
    pressureGraph->graph(0)->setPen(QPen(Qt::green));
    pressureGraph->graph(1)->setPen(QPen(Qt::red));
    pressureGraph->xAxis->setLabel("Temps (ms)");
    pressureGraph->yAxis->setLabel("Pression (bars)");
    pressureGraph->yAxis->setRange(0, 1);
    firstTabLayout->addWidget(pressureGraph);


    // Créer les boutons de contrôle du graphe de pression d'accélérateur et de frein

    QPushButton* pauseButton = new QPushButton("Mettre en pause", firstTab);
    QPushButton* nextButton = new QPushButton("Milliseconde suivante", firstTab);
    QPushButton* previousButton = new QPushButton("Milliseconde précédente", firstTab);
    QPushButton* forwardButton = new QPushButton("Avancer x3", firstTab);
    QPushButton* backwardButton = new QPushButton("Reculer x3", firstTab);
    firstTabLayout->addWidget(pauseButton);
    firstTabLayout->addWidget(nextButton);
    firstTabLayout->addWidget(previousButton);
    firstTabLayout->addWidget(forwardButton);
    firstTabLayout->addWidget(backwardButton);


    // Ajouter l'onglet au widget QTabWidget

    tabWidget->addTab(firstTab, "Graphique de pression d'accélérateur et de frein");


    // Créer le deuxième onglet affichant un tableau de données de télémétrie

    QWidget* secondTab = new QWidget();
    QVBoxLayout* secondTabLayout = new QVBoxLayout(secondTab);


    // Créer le modèle de données et le tableau

    QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(0, 9, secondTab);
    model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, "Temps (ms)");
    model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, "Distance (m)");
    model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, "Vitesse (m/s)");
    model->setHeaderData(3, Qt::Horizontal, "Accélération (m/s^2)");
    model->setHeaderData(4, Qt::Horizontal, "Pression d'accélérateur (bars)");
    model->setHeaderData(5, Qt::Horizontal, "Pression de frein (bars)");
    model->setHeaderData(6, Qt::Horizontal, "Position GPS X (m)");
    model->setHeaderData(7, Qt::Horizontal, "Position GPS Y (m)");


    //Créer l'onglet secondaire

    QTableView* tableView = new QTableView(secondTab);
    tableView->setModel(model);
    secondTabLayout->addWidget(tableView);


    // Ajouter l'onglet au widget QTabWidget

    tabWidget->addTab(secondTab, "Données de télémétrie");


    // Créer le bouton permettant de changer d'onglet

    QPushButton* switchTabButton = new QPushButton("Changer d'onglet", centralWidget);
    mainLayout->addWidget(switchTabButton);


    // Connecter le signal clicked() du bouton à un slot qui changera l'onglet sélectionné dans le widget QTabWidget

    QObject::connect(switchTabButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [&tabWidget]() {
        int currentIndex = tabWidget->currentIndex();
        int newIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % tabWidget->count();
        tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(newIndex);
        });



    // --------------------- Ouverture du Fichier -------------------


    // Ouvrir le fichier de données de télémétrie en lecture

    QFile file("telemetry.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        // Afficher une erreur si le fichier ne peut pas être ouvert
        QMessageBox::critical(nullptr, "Erreur", "Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier de données de télémétrie");
        return -1;
    }


    // Collecter les données de télémétrie depuis le fichier

    QTextStream in(&file);
    QVector<TelemetryData> data;
    while (!in.atEnd()) {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        QStringList fields = line.split("\t");
        if (fields.size() != 8) {
            // Afficher une erreur si le nombre de champs est incorrect
            QMessageBox::critical(nullptr, "Erreur", "Format de données de télémétrie incorrect");
            return -1;
        }

        TelemetryData datum;
        datum.time = fields[0].toDouble();
        datum.distance = fields[1].toDouble();
        datum.speed = fields[2].toDouble();
        datum.acceleration = fields[3].toDouble();
        datum.acceleratorPressure = fields[4].toDouble();
        datum.brakePressure = fields[5].toDouble();
        datum.gpsPositionX = fields[6].toDouble();
        datum.gpsPositionY = fields[7].toDouble();
        data.append(datum);
    }
    file.close();



    // -------------- Affinage des affichages --------------


    // Créer un objet gnuplot pour dessiner la gauge de vitesse

    Gnuplot gp;
    gp << "set terminal qt size 350,200 font ',14'\n";
    gp << "set style data line\n";
    gp << "set xrange [-1:1]\n";
    gp << "set yrange [-1:1]\n";
    gp << "set border 0\n";
    gp << "set tics out\n";
    gp << "set nokey\n";
    gp << "unset colorbox\n";
    gp << "set object 1 circle at 0,0 size 1.1 fc rgb 'white'\n";
    gp << "set object 2 circle at 0,0 size 1 fc rgb 'black'\n";
    gp << "set object 3 circle at 0,0 size 0.9 fc rgb 'red'\n";
    gp << "set object 4 circle at 0,0 size 0.1 fc rgb 'black'\n";
    gp << "set object 5 circle at 0,0 size 0.07 fc rgb 'white'\n";


    // Créer une image du circuit vu d'en haut

    QImage circuitImage("circuit.png");
    QLabel* circuitLabel = new QLabel(centralWidget);
    circuitLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(circuitImage));
    circuitLabel->setScaledContents(true);
    circuitLabel->setFixedSize(500, 500);
    mainLayout->addWidget(circuitLabel);


    // Dessiner un cercle rouge à la position de la voiture sur l'image du circuit

    QGraphicsScene* circuitScene = new QGraphicsScene(circuitLabel);
    QGraphicsEllipseItem* car = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(0, 0, 10, 10);
    car->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::red));
    circuitScene->addItem(car);
    QGraphicsView* circuitView = new QGraphicsView(circuitScene, circuitLabel);
    circuitView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    circuitView->setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);
    circuitView->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    circuitView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    circuitView->setFixedSize(500, 500);


    // Créer une jauge de vitesse

    QLabel* speedGauge = new QLabel(centralWidget);
    speedGauge->setFixedSize(350, 200);
    speedGauge->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(gp.plot(QString(""), "", "", "", false).scaled(350, 200)));
    mainLayout->addWidget(speedGauge);


    // Afficher la fenêtre principale

    mainWindow.show();



    // ---------------- Fonction Temps réel ---------------



    // Initialiser l'index de la donnée de télémétrie actuellement affichée

    int dataIndex = 0;


    // Initialiser un booléen indiquant si la lecture en temps réel est en pause

    bool paused = false;


    // Boucle principale de mise à jour de l'affichage en temps réel

    while (true) {

        // Mettre à jour le graphique de pression d'accélérateur et de frein

        pressureGraph->graph(0)->addData(data[dataIndex].time, data[dataIndex].acceleratorPressure);
        pressureGraph->graph(1)->addData(data[dataIndex].time, data[dataIndex].brakePressure);
        pressureGraph->xAxis->setRange(data[dataIndex].time, 8, Qt::AlignRight);
        pressureGraph->replot();


        // Mettre à jour la jauge de vitesse

        double speedRatio = data[dataIndex].speed / 140.0;  // 140 km/h est la vitesse maximale
        gp << "set object 4 circle at " << QString::number(speedRatio * std::sin(M_PI / 4)).toStdString()
            << "," << QString::number(-speedRatio * std::cos(M_PI / 4)).toStdString()
            << " size 0.1 fc rgb 'black'\n";
        speedGauge->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(gp.plot(QString(""), "", "", "", false).scaled(350, 200)));


        // Mettre à jour la position de la voiture sur l'image du circuit

        car->setPos(250 + data[dataIndex].gpsPositionX * 3, 250 - data[dataIndex].gpsPositionY * 3);  // 250, 250 est le centre de l'image


        // Mettre à jour l'affichage du tableau de données de télémétrie

        for (int i = 0; i < model->rowCount(); ++i) {
            model->setData(model->index(i, 0), data[i].time);
            model->setData(model->index(i, 1), data[i].distance);
            model->setData(model->index(i, 2), data[i].speed);
            model->setData(model->index(i, 3), data[i].acceleration);
            model->setData(model->index(i, 4), data[i].acceleratorPressure);
            model->setData(model->index(i, 5), data[i].brakePressure);
            model->setData(model->index(i, 6), data[i].gpsPositionX);
            model->setData(model->index(i, 7), data[i].gpsPositionY);
        }
        tableView->scrollTo(model->index(dataIndex, 0));


        // Attendre 1 milliseconde avant de mettre à jour à nouveau l'affichage

        QThread::msleep(1);


        // Si la lecture en temps réel n'est pas en pause, passer à la donnée de télémétrie suivante

        if (!paused) {
            ++dataIndex;
        }
        if (dataIndex >= data.size()) {
            dataIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

There is no error and when I build the solution, it works fine, saying the operation was succesful, however when I try to debug it, no .exe is found.

Here is what I get when I build the solution :
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Telemetrie_PITA, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I checked the project files and it is true, there is no .exe in sight.

To verify whether the error would come from my project or my installation, I ran a simple HelloWorld project which worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Maybe the problem is your antivirus.

Comment: Tried both enabled and disabled, neither work

Comment: How are you building this with msvc? Are you using CMake or the VSAddon?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea, I installed all the addons I could so I would avoid this kind of error.

Comment: A Qt application requires additional steps / tools installed in Visual Studio Community to build.

Comment: Please edit your question and copy and paste the output from the build that is in the "Output" tab of visual studio.

Comment: I tried my best to install these QT addons but I cannot make it work

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is and even more difficult because you are very new to this and don't fully understand what you are doing. Can you even attempt to debug in the VS debugger? Does it tell you that the executable is not found?

Answer (score 0):

1. `Menu -> Build -> Build Solution` perform.
2. .exe file is default located in `C:\Users\DESKTOP NAME\source\repos\PROJECT NANE\PROJECT NAME\bin\Debug` path.
3. .exe can also be forcibly deleted Anti-Virus Program.

Comment: The build solution only works for the basic HelloWorld program but not for mine.

C:\Users\Adrie\OneDrive\Documents\EFT\PITA\Telemetrie_PITA\x64\Debug is empty.

Comment: Did you divide into two builds in one project?

Comment: No I just built one first, then when I tried again I cleaned then clicked build again so I don't think there are 2 builds

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Have you tried moving code to a new project? its work?
I thought you create exe file deleted by anti-virus program

Comment: Yes I did retry a few times with new projects but I always get the same error, it looks like the problem comes from the libraries I cannot install

Comment: Have you tried additional dependent builds for the QT library header?
Please revise the your posting and let me know when you get your problem.